# const *const pointers in function parameters

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have a question about best practices involving pointers in function parameters and whether they should be specified as `*const` or `const *const`. I know there are varying opinions on use, or excessive use, of `const`, but at least some use is a good way to catch accidental mistakes.

Say you have the following function, which is part of the implementation of a queue based on a linked list:

```
void enqueue(struct queue *q, void *data)
{
    struct queue_node *item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
    item->data = data;

    [add node to linked list, specifics are not relevant here]
}
```

`struct queue_node` is defined as

```
struct queue_node {
        struct queue_node *next;
        void *data;
};
```

`data` is not meant to be modified in this function, so it seems like a good idea for `data` to be of type `void *const` so you can't accidentally do something like `data = item->data` instead of `item->data = data`.

The next level would be to define `data` as `const void *const` which means you also can't change what `data` points to. However, this leads to a warning about discarding the `const` qualifier from the pointer. And if I understand correctly, further use of such a pointer is considered undefined behavior. Using a cast (`item->data = (void *)data`) seems clunky.

What's the best approach here? Is `const void *const` unnecessarily over-protective? It feels like `void *const` is sufficient to catch most errors.

Comment: If `item->data` has type `void *`, I think it makes sense the the `data` parameter to be `void *` or `void * const` even though the function does not modify the object pointed to by `data`. I would only use `const void * data` or `const void * const data` if `item->data` had type `const void *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since changes to function parameters aren't reflected in the calling function, there's little reason to make sure the parameters themselves are read-only.  It *is* useful however to ensure that what a pointer parameter points to doesn't change.  So if you don't want what `data` points to to be changed, you would change the function signature to:

```
void enqueue(struct queue *q, const void *data)
```

Note that this will work only if the `data` member of `struct queue_node` has type `const void *`.  If it doesn't, then you don't want to use `const` on the `data` parameter.

Comment: (original post edited to include struct definition)  ```data``` is type ```void *``` so later retrieval can be cast-less and the object pointed to can be modified.

Comment: @sj95126 That means the function doesn't guarantee `data` won't be modified and therefore the parameter should *not* be `const`.

Comment: OK, thanks. It sounds like the solution is to just stick with ```void *```. This won't protect against something like ```data = item->data``` instead of ```item->data = data``` but the effect of that should be obvious when there's an item in the queue with missing or corrupt ```data```.